# Easyphp 17.0 not starting on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, easyphp

I have an easyphp installation on a Windows 2016 server, my problem is that EasyPhp does not start at Windows startup.

What are the possibilities for him to start alone?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I already searched the answer here, it was : right click the .exe file and choose unblock.
for the default settings of windows server prevent running exec files.